# Derivative of $\cos^x \theta$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I wondered how to calculatethe following derivative :
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\cos^x\theta)$$
where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

It is kind of silly question, but I could not find the way to search at the internet.

Thanks.

Comment: Is $\theta$ a constant?  If so, this is just of the form $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$.

Comment: are $\theta$ and $x$ independent variables?

Comment: I vote for writing $(\cos \theta)^x$ when $x$ is not a positive integer.  Then we can clearly see this is of the form $a^x$ as lulu notes.

Answer (score 1):

If $\theta$ is just a constant (meaning that $x$ and $\theta$ are independent variables), then :

$$\cos^x\theta=(\cos \theta)^x = e^{x \ln (\cos \theta)}$$

and thus $(\cos^x \theta)' = (e^{x \ln(\cos \theta)})' = (x\ln(\cos \theta))' \cdot e^{x \ln (\cos \theta)} = \ln(\cos \theta) e^{x \ln(\cos \theta)}= \ln(\cos \theta)\cos^x \theta.$

Answer (score 1):

As noted: $$y=\cos^x\theta=(\cos\theta)^x=e^{x\ln(\cos\theta)}$$

Treating $\theta$ as another variable:
$$y'=(x\ln(\cos\theta))'\cdot e^{x\ln(\cos\theta)}$$

Let $p=x\to p'=1$ and $q=\ln(\cos\theta)\to q'=\frac{-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=-\tan\theta\frac{d\theta}{dx}$

The product rule:
$$(pq)'=p'q+q'p$$
Tells us:
$$(x\ln(\cos\theta))'=\ln(\cos\theta)-x\tan\theta\frac{d\theta}{dx}$$
Subbing this back in, noting $e^{x\ln(\cos\theta)}=\cos^x\theta$, we get:
$$y'=\cos^x\theta\ln(\cos\theta)-x\cos^x\theta\tan\theta\frac{d\theta}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

Sounds simple, if I get the question rightly. $$\dfrac{d(\cos^x\theta )}{dx}=\cos^{x}\theta\ln\cos\theta$$